# Ruby not installing json -v 1.8.1 as part of bundle, ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I've tried installing using as part of the bundle and using sudo, but I get the same error message every time. I'm currently on `Ruby 2.0.0 and Rails 4.1.8`. I'm not sure what is going on. The exact error message below:

> Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
>   Resolving dependencies...
>     Using rake 10.4.2 Using i18n 0.6.11
>
> Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby -r
>   ./siteconf20141218-80226-brqexc.rb extconf.rb  mkmf.rb can't find
>   header files for ruby at
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h
>
> extconf failed, exit code 1
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.1 for inspection. Results
>   logged to
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-14/2.0.0/json-1.8.1/gem_make.out
>   An error occurred while installing json (1.8.1), and Bundler cannot
>   continue. Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.1'` succeeds before
>   bundling.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: I've run into similar issues after upgrading to Yosemite.  gcc version was the root of all of them.  `brew rm gcc46`, `brew install libxml2` and then
`brew install libxslt` helped me.  I did a lot of `brew doctor` in the process.

Comment: xcode and command tools installation may help as well.

Comment: I too ran into this issue after upgrading to Yosemite. If you have xcode and command tools installed, you have to open xcode and agree to their terms before command line tools function properly.

Comment: How do I make sure command line is installed? I did xcode-select --install but there was no GUI pop-up, only an outline of usage. I am unable to properly install Homebrew because of this issue, so I can't yet use brew doctor.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into similar error on Ubuntu and all I needed to do was:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
```

For Mac, the following gist seems worth to have a look into: [Setup mac for ruby dev](https://gist.github.com/mcls/3118518)